# Распознавание Qr Code

Tags: распознавание, qr

Здравствуйте. Мне необходимо написать простенькую программу для распознавания Qr-кода с изображения(распознаем qr-код только определённого формата), причем нельзя использовать готовые библиотеки. Не подскажите, где можно найти информацию по данному вопросу(желательно - русскоязычную)?

Comment: [Пожалуйста](https://geektimes.ru/post/256932/).

Comment: @post_zeew спасибо, но я имел ввиду методы компьютерного распознавания, какие алгоритмы стоит использовать на каждой стадии и прочее.

Answer (score 0):

2 самые распространенные библиотеки

- ZBAR http://zbar.sourceforge.net/
- ZXing https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Обе с открытым кодом (по ссылкам).

Если нельзя использовать библиотеки, то использовать их код я подозреваю никто Вам запретить не сможет? ))